# Extract string between special characters - and / into a new field ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, python-parser, string

Can I create a field calc expression in ArcGIS 10.3 to print a selection between special characters?

I would like to extract a selection of string from field [FolderPath] to a new field [Name]. The string is between a hyphen and a forward slash.

What I have in field **[FolderPath]**  example string:  *264K - Name of Place/FeatureType*

What I want in field **[Name]** target string: *Name of Place*

Answer (score 10):

#### Solution with re module

You can use the built-in `re` module in Python for that.

```
import re
sr = re.split(' - |/',s)[1]
```

Field calculator view (where *FeatureStr* is the source field with `264K - Name of Place/FeatureType` and *Split* is the output field with : `Name of Place`.

[image]

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def splitText(field):
  import re
  return re.split(' - |/', field)[1]
```

Field to be equal to:

```
splitText(!FeatureStr!)
```

#### Alternative solution with no re module:

```
!FeatureStr!.split(' - ')[1].split('/')[0]
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. Regex is a powerful tool which can be helpful in many cases when you need to split various strings. It might be a bit hard to master it, so when need just a quick fix - you can use the str.split() method multiple times iterating results - `!FeatureStr!.split(' - ')[1].split('/')[0]` would also work. And you wouldn't need a definition block. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is `import`ing *inside* the function necessary, or can you put it outside?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to 'field calculator  >  String functions'. Select the `Left()` function.  Inside bracket of left:

`Left(Column_name, No. of characters to extract)`

Hit Apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need to extract a variable length string from within a longer string, but where the left and right lengths of characters to be removed from the source string were fixed (but not necessarily the same).

I used this expression in the field calculator for the new string:

```
Left(RIGHT([field],Len([field] )-N1),Len(RIGHT([field],Len([field] )-N1))-N2)
```

Where:

- [field] = source string
- N1 = number of characters to remove from the
  left of the string
- N2 = number of characters to remove from the right
  of the string